# Problema con punteros a ficheros de texto en C

Tags: c, funciones, punteros, estructuras

Buenas Dias para el que lo lea y felices fiestas.

Estaba haciendo un programa en C que lea de un fichero de texto datos bancarios inventados de 5 personas y los muestre por pantalla pero me da error al llamar a la funcion leerDatps y no se como solucionarlo.El error que me marca es este: "expected 'struct opBanco **' but argument is of type 'struct opBanco (*)[5]"
Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

struct fecha{
int dia,mes,anio;
};

struct opBanco{
char nombre[50]; //Nombre y apellidos
char codigo[15]; // Codigo de la tarjeta
char oper;  //Operacion: 'i'-> ingresar , 'r'->retirar , 't'->transferir
float importe; //Importe en euros
struct fecha fechaOp; //Fecha de la operacion bancaria
}datPersonas[N];

void leerDatos(FILE *f , struct opBanco *datPersonas[]);
void escribirDatos(struct opBanco datPersonas[]);

int main(){
     FILE *f,*fi;

    f = fopen("fichero.txt","r");
    fi = fopen("ficheroIngresos.txt","w");

   if(f==NULL){
      printf("Fichero no encontrado.\n");
   }else{
      printf("Fichero encontrado.\n");
   }

leerDatos(f,&datPersonas);
escribirDatos(datPersonas);

return 0;
}

void leerDatos(FILE *f , struct opBanco *datPersonas[]){
int i;

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    while(!feof(f)){
        fgets(datPersonas[i]->nombre,50,f);
        fgets(datPersonas[i]->codigo,15,f);
        fscanf(f,"%c",&datPersonas[i]->oper);
        fscanf(f,"%f",&datPersonas[i]->importe);
        fscanf(f,"%d/%d/%d",&datPersonas[i]->fechaOp.dia,&datPersonas[i]->fechaOp.mes,&datPersonas[i]->fechaOp.anio);
     }
  }

}

void escribirDatos(struct opBanco datPersonas[]){
int i;

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("Nombre y apellidos: %s",datPersonas[i].nombre);
    printf("Codigo de tarjeta: %s",datPersonas[i].codigo);
    switch(datPersonas[i].oper){
        case 'i': printf("Operacion: Ingresar.\n"); break;
        case 'r': printf("Operacion: Retirar.\n"); break;
        case 't': printf("Operacion: Transferir.\n"); break;
    }
    printf("Importe de la operacion: %f\n",datPersonas[i].importe);
    printf("Fecha: %d/%d/%d",datPersonas[i].fechaOp.dia,datPersonas[i].fechaOp.mes,datPersonas[i].fechaOp.anio);
 }
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradeceria , tengo otro fichero porque mi intencion era introducir los datos de los usuarios que hubieran ingresado dinero en otro fichero , pero primero estaba probando que muestre los datos por pantalla.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > El error que me marca es este: "expected 'struct opBanco **' but argument is of type 'struct opBanco (*)[5]

El problema radica en esta línea:

```
leerDatos(f,&datPersonas);
```

`datPersonas` es un puntero que apunta a 5 estructuras de tipo `opBanco`, pero el parámetro es un puntero doble, es decir, lo que recibe es una dirección de memoria de un puntero de tipo `opBanco`.

Por más que le antepongamos el ampersand a `datPersonas` al invocar la función, no estaremos pasando la dirección de memoria del puntero en si, sino la dirección base (del primer elemento) de la primera estructura al que apunta el puntero `datPersonas` y por esa razón da error de compilación y es más, si el compilador no nos diera ningún error o advertencia, sería peligroso, el programa dejaría de funcionar debido a que, se estaría intentando acceder a direcciones que al programa no le pertenece y esto ocurriría cuando la función `leerDatos` comience a ejecutarse.

La solución es cambiar la declaración y definición de `leerDatos`:

```
void leerDatos(FILE *f , struct opBanco *datPersonas);

void leerDatos(FILE *f , struct opBanco *datPersonas){
int i;

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    while(!feof(f)){
        fgets(datPersonas[i].nombre,50,f);
        fgets(datPersonas[i].codigo,15,f);
        fscanf(f,"%c",&datPersonas[i].oper);
        fscanf(f,"%f",&datPersonas[i].importe);
        fscanf(f,"%d/%d/%d",&datPersonas[i].fechaOp.dia,&datPersonas[i].fechaOp.mes,&datPersonas[i].fechaOp.anio);
     }
  }
}
```

Básicamente lo único que se debe alterar es el segundo parámetro de la función, es decir, que sea declarado como un puntero simple (espera la dirección base del primer miembro de la estructura de tipo `opBanco`).

Y llamas la función de esta forma:

```
leerDatos(f, datPersonas);
```

Que es equivalente a:

```
leerDatos(f, &datPersonas[0]);
```